# Use K8s Deployment Hostname In YAML Config

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to convert some K8s examples from ReplicationControllers to Deployments. These examples are for a Selenium grid located: https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/selenium

When I run the examples as-is, my selenium-hub and selenium-nodes connect successfully. However, when I tried to convert `selenium-hub-rc.yaml` and `selenium-node-chrome-rc.yaml` into Deployments, the selenium-nodes will not connect to the selenium-hub.

In `selenium-node-chrome-rc.yaml` there are [these variables](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/selenium/selenium-node-chrome-rc.yaml#L21):

```
...
env:
- name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR 
value: "selenium-hub"
- name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT 
value: "4444"
...
```

`HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR` is the ip/hostname of the selenium-hub. The `selenium-hub-rc.yaml` shows the phrase `selenium-hub` in [many locations](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/selenium/selenium-hub-rc.yaml#L4). **Question 1**: which of these is actually defining the host name? (`.metadata.name`, `.spec.selector.app`, ...?)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub <-------------------
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub <-------------------
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub <-------------------
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-hub <-------------------
    spec:
      containers:
- name: selenium-hub <-------------------
....
```

Now, I changed this `selenium-hub-rc.yaml` to a deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub-deployment <---------- this is the hostname?
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: selenium-grid
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: selenium-hub <--------- this is the hostname?
        image: selenium/hub
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4444
...
```

But now the selenium-node won't connect and I believe it is due to `HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR`. I have tried:

```
- name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR
  value: "selenium-hub"
```

and

```
- name: HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR
  value: "selenium-hub-deployment"
```

Neither worked. **Question 2**: What is the hostname for a deployment? It seemed straight forward in the ReplicationController yaml e.g. `selenium-hub`, but I can't get it to work as a deployment.

<s>Note, I have not changed [the service](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/selenium/selenium-hub-svc.yaml) in any way.</s> Actually I DID change it and that partially caused my initial issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea of where the hostname was coming from was wrong. According to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/):

> Every Service defined in the cluster (including the DNS server itself) is assigned a DNS name.

and

> Currently when a pod is created, its hostname is the Pod’s metadata.name value.

So the hostname is actually the name of the service. The last sentence in my question says I did not change the service in anyway. That was an unintentional lie. I did change the service name, or else `selenium-hub` as the hostname would have worked.

Changing `HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR` to the `.metadata.name` of the *service* got me closer. The connection was timing out, though.

I believed some of the configuration was wrong in my service yaml. So instead of using my yaml file, I created the service via:
`kubectl expose deployment <deployment name here>`

This created a service and I checked the selenium-hub and the node was finally connected. So there was an issue in my service yaml. To get the correct configuration I exported the currently working service:
`kubectl get svc <service name here> -o yaml --export`

I copied the exported configuration to my service yaml file and it also worked. Here was the difference between the service yamls

```
old yaml (copied from GitHub example above)
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub-service
  labels:
    app: selenium-grid
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4444
    targetPort: 4444
    protocol: TCP ------------- [added in new config]
    name: port0 ------------- [deleted in new config]
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: NodePort ------------- [deleted in new config]
  sessionAffinity: None
```

I am not sure why adding `.spec.ports[0].protocol` and deleting `.spec.type` and `.spec.ports[0].name` fixed the issue. If anyone could clarify in the comments I would appreciate it.